# How to detect application runs foreground or background using Single Activity or Java class

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I want to sent report to the server which means how long user Use the application in single day..I can achieve using this to method

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        //commonclassMethod.getInstance(UserForground);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        //commonclassMethod.getInstance(UserBackground);
    }
```

What happen  i need to call call this method in every activity....

What i need,is there any possible to find user `forground` `background` method in single **java class** or **activity**..

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you can use a service to check duration of usage, and in every activity just start and stop service in onResume and onStop method.

Comment: Inside  Service what should i have to do.

Comment: you can create a sticky service , broadcast the events using LocalBroadcastManager and listen those events in you service to perform the actions accordingly

Answer (score 2):

You can can achieve this just by adding an method isAppIsInBackground(Context context) in class which is extending Application class

In that class define that method:

```
public static boolean isAppIsInBackground(Context context) {
        boolean isInBackground = true;
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
            List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
            for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
                if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                    for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                        if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                            isInBackground = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
            ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
            if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                isInBackground = false;
            }
        }
        return isInBackground;
    }
```

It will true if app is in background

Or another better approach would be just extend your each `Activity` by an **BaseActivity**, in this **BaseActivity's** override methods

```
protected void onResume() { 
super.onResume(); 
//commonclassMethod.getInstance(UserForground); 
} 

protected void onStop() { 
super.onStop(); 
//commonclassMethod.getInstance(UserBackground); 
}
```

Comment: Where i have to validate this boolean condition  inside Broadcast Receiver or what

Comment: You can make an service class or if you have, which will trigger the changes to server from isAppIsInBackground()

Comment: Or another better approach would be just extend your each activity by an BaseActivity, in this BaseActivity's override methods
     protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        //commonclassMethod.getInstance(UserForground);
    }

  
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        //commonclassMethod.getInstance(UserBackground);
    }

Answer (score 1):

You can implement callback method to solve your case.

For example:

You create an interface first, then define a method, which would act as a callback. In this example we would have two classes, one classA and another classB

Interface:

```
public interface OnCustomEventListener{
  public void onEvent();   //method, which can have parameters
}
```

the listener itself in classB (we only set the listener in classB)

private OnCustomEventListener mListener; //listener field

```
//setting the listener
public void setCustomEventListener(OnCustomEventListener eventListener) {
   this.mListener=eventListener;
}
```

in classA, how we start listening for whatever classB has to tell

```
classB.setCustomEventListener(new OnCustomEventListener(){
    public void onEvent(){
       //do whatever you want to do when the event is performed.
    }
});
```

how do we trigger an event from classB (for example on button pressed)

```
if(this.mListener!=null){
   this.mListener.onEvent();
}
```

Here is some nice tutorials [link1](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/09/implement-callback-function-with.html),[link2](http://www.edumobile.org/android/how-to-implement-callback-method/),[link3](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077462/learn-java/java-tip-10--implement-callback-routines-in-java.html) which describes callbacks and the use-case well.

Comment: Thank you..let me check.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class extending application and use registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks() to get the activity lifecycle

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
           if(activity.getClass().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName())){

               //Do the required thing here
           }
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {

        }
    });
  }
}
```

Also dont forget to register activity in manifest

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApp"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

1) Do a abstract BaseActivity and make all Activities extend it. This way you only write the code in one BaseActivity and all children activities consume it.

2) Use a custom counter class to monitor app to foreground. Here is my implementation of it if you would like to copy it.

```
 /**
 * Created by App Studio 35 on 6/23/17.
 */
public class AppLifeCycleTracker implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {;

    /*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // METHODS
    *////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private static final String TAG = Globals.SEARCH_STRING + AppLifeCycleTracker.class.getSimpleName();
    private static AppLifeCycleTracker INSTANCE;
    private static int numActivitiesInMemory = 0;
    private ArrayList<IAppToForegroundListener> mAppToForegroundListeners;
    private boolean isRefreshing;
    private Object lockAccess = new Object();
    private AlertDialog mAlertDialog = null;


    /*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // PROPERTIES
    *////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private ArrayList<IAppToForegroundListener> getAppToForegroundListeners(){
        return mAppToForegroundListeners == null ? mAppToForegroundListeners = new ArrayList<IAppToForegroundListener>() : mAppToForegroundListeners;

    }
    public boolean getIsRefreshing(){
        return isRefreshing;
    }
    public boolean getAppIsInBackground(){
        return numActivitiesInMemory < 1;

    }


    /*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // CONSTRUCTOR
    *////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private AppLifeCycleTracker(){

    }
    public synchronized static AppLifeCycleTracker getInstance(){
        if(INSTANCE == null){
            INSTANCE = new AppLifeCycleTracker();

        }

        return INSTANCE;

    }


    /*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // LIFE CYCLE OVERRIDES
    *////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityStarted(final Activity activity) {
        //App went into background, so set a flag to avoid loading while we refresh
        if(numActivitiesInMemory == 0 && !(activity instanceof SplashScreenActivity) && !(activity instanceof CreateAccountActivity)){
            A35Log.v(TAG, "App Returned to Foreground, refreshing Token");
            //first load on splash it goes from 0 to 1 so hold off on splash
            synchronized (lockAccess) {
                isRefreshing = true;

            }

            if (DeviceInfo.getInstance(activity).getIsConnectedToInternet()) {
                CognitoManager.refreshToken(activity, new GenericHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        A35Log.v(TAG, "Token Refresh Complete, notifying listeners");
                        //we are good, keep going
                        for(IAppToForegroundListener listener : getAppToForegroundListeners()){
                            listener.onRefreshTokenComplete();

                        }

                        synchronized (lockAccess) {
                            isRefreshing = false;

                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
                        //boot them to login screen
                        if(activity instanceof LoginActivity || activity instanceof SplashScreenActivity){
                            return;
                        }
                        startLoginActivity(activity);
                        synchronized (lockAccess) {
                            isRefreshing = false;

                        }

                    }
                });

            } else {
                showInternetRequiredDialog(activity);

            }

        }

        numActivitiesInMemory++;

    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {


    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {


    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
        numActivitiesInMemory--;
        //if numActivities == 0 then you are in the background

    }
    @Override
    public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {


    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {


    }


    /*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // METHODS
    *////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public void addAppToForegroundListener(IAppToForegroundListener listener){
        getAppToForegroundListeners().add(listener);

    }
    public void removeAppToForegroundListener(IAppToForegroundListener listener){
        getAppToForegroundListeners().remove(listener);

    }
    private void startLoginActivity(final Activity activity){
        ((AMApplication) activity.getApplication()).logoutCurrentUser(activity, false, false, null, true, null);

    }


    /*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // INTERFACES
    *////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public interface IAppToForegroundListener {

        /*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // METHODS
        *////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        void onRefreshTokenComplete();

    }
    private void showInternetRequiredDialog(Activity activity){
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        builder.setTitle("Error").setMessage("Internet is required to use this app").setNegativeButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if(mAlertDialog != null && mAlertDialog.isShowing()) {
                    mAlertDialog.dismiss();

                }

            }

        });

        mAlertDialog = builder.create();
        mAlertDialog.show();

    }

}
```

Of course this does a little more then you are looking for as mine manages refreshing the token with cognito and forcing refresh on returning from background and things like that, so just disregard that piece. But the rest is all the same still. Hope that helps.

I'm assuming you don't need an example of a BaseActivity so I won't patronize you by pasting that.

Startup in Application class

```
  @Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
   registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(AppLifeCycleTracker.getInstance());

}
```

Then you ONLY need to access from BaseActivity or BaseFragment IF you need to be notified when the app is in foreground or background at an Activity or fragment level. Which for your situation is not the case.

But if you ever wanted to use it, simply do this:

```
   @Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    AppLifeCycleTracker.getInstance().addAppToForegroundListener(this);

}
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    AppLifeCycleTracker.getInstance().removeAppToForegroundListener(this);

}
```

But again, I must emphasize, this part is ONLY if you care to make your activity or fragment be aware of when the app comes back to foreground to force refresh or other behaviors. Replace onDetach with onDestroy if using Activity, but for your scenario you can skip that whole last section of code, you don't need it.

Comment: My understating i have to Extends this `AppLifeCycleTracker` java cass  in every activity right.

Comment: No just create it in the Application class onCreate in the Application. I'll update my answer to display

Comment: Ok sir thak you also where i have to call retrofit method to sent forground and background method.

Comment: That is up to you, but you can see where I do numActivitiesInMemory (-- or ++) those are indications of activities coming in or out of memory. So if the number gets to 0 then you are in the background, if it gets above 0 after it was previously 0 then you are back in foreground. You can see the logic for calling the listeners to notify of "back to foreground", the logic for "going to background" would need to be added to the (--) section to check if we are going to 0, for my sample I didn't code that piece for you, but it's easy enough. Make sense? Updated answer for you